# How to encrypt/decrypt using salt in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

Not sure where to begin. I've tried Google and all the examples are really complex and don't explain things very well.

I'd just like to learn how to encrypt/decrypt using salt in C#. Preferably a step-by-step guide so I can really understand what's going on. Just trying to add some security to a site I'm working on. Thanks.

Comment: Salt has nothing to do with encryption.  You need to learn about encryption and hashing.

Comment: How will you "add security" ? That's a much more important question than how to apply the lib classes.

Comment: You should probably read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: **Adding encryption often does not add security.** Encryption is useful for only a tiny subset of security problems. You are putting the cart before the horse here. What you need to do is first write a *threat model* that clearly describes all the vulnerabilities and threats in the software, and then figure out how to mitigate them **using off-the-shelf parts written by experts**. Only then should you even consider writing your own encryption code. Assume that you *will* get it wrong, and you *will* write an insecure web site that you think is actually secure. That's a bad place to be.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this article, which covers all the basics and has a helper library:

[Cryptography 101 for the .NET Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/Crypto.aspx)

Comment: A quick browse shows that it does not go into the reasons to apply cryptography. It handles encryption without warning that encryption does not take integrity or authentication into account (just confidentiality, and even then only when applied correctly). Be warned that applying crypto without knowing these topics is a dangerous situation. Maybe someone can recommend a book?